# Asignación condicional con DataRow C#

Tags: c#, datarow

Existe una forma simple de asignar un valor de un **DataRow** con el operador condicional, de lo contrario, cual seria la mejor forma de lograr algo parecido.

```
int lastParent = 0;
foreach (DataRow dataRow in parentTable.Rows)
{
    //Si la columna "IdParent" existe que asigne el valor.
    lastParent = (dataRow?["IdParent"]) ? (int)dataRow["IdParent"] : (int)dataRow["IdUser"];
}
```

Espero que alguien pueda ayudarme. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

si lo que intentas es ver si existe la columna con nombre `IdParent` el código seria algo así:

```
int lastParent = 0;
foreach (DataRow dataRow in parentTable.Rows)
{
    //Si la columna "IdParent" existe que asigne el valor.

    lastParent = parentTable.Columns.Contains("IdParent") ? (int) dataRow["IdParent"] : (int)dataRow["IdUser"];

}
```

Pero si lo que intentas es comprobar que en la fila en la que te encuentras la columna `IdParent` (que sabes que existe) tiene valor quedaría algo así:

```
int lastParent = 0;
foreach (DataRow dataRow in parentTable.Rows)
{
    //Si la columna "IdParent" tiene un valor no nulo

    lastParent = (int?) dataRow["IdParent"] ?? (int) dataRow["IdParent"];
}
```

Espero que te ayude.

Comment: Gracias @ElGerar.

Answer (score 0):

```
int i=0;
                            while(DataGridView.RowCount>0)
                                if(DataGridView.Rows[i].Cells["IdParent"].Value !=null)
                                    lastParent = //Tu asignación
```

Responde si te sirve.

Comment: Por favor agregue una descripción a su respuesta. ¿Qué hace el código?